# CRC calculation for Serial ATA (SATA)

Tags: vhdl, crc32, sata

After reading a lot I came to know that there is no SINGLE method of calculating CRC.
I need method/algorithm/VHDL code for calculating CRC specifically for Serial ATA (SATA)

Comment: You are right. There is not a single algorithm. Why don't you choose one and implement it? (You certainly don't expect us to do it for you?)

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: SATA mandates a specific algorithm. OP can't choose their own and expect it to interoperate with existing hardware.

Comment: It still sounds like "type it for me in google" kind of non-question. Not productive.

Answer (score 4):

SATA uses IEEE 802.3 CRC. Here are some relevant resources:

- [Serial ATA Bus](http://www.interfacebus.com/Design_Connector_Serial_ATA.html)
- [Design and Implementation of a SATA Host Controller on a Spartan-6 FPGA](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:549840/FULLTEXT02&ei=HYBFUf_HBc3y0gXunYGACg&usg=AFQjCNGjLe6OYdPyX3imxAlwv5IfkABMaw&sig2=C6G81NSCTXFXZaJdIRNGIw&bvm=bv.43828540,d.d2k) (section 2.7.2 Error detection with CRC)
- [IEEE 802.3 Cyclic Redundancy Check](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp209.pdf) (Xilinx application note)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [complete description of that CRC](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/17plus.htm#crc.cat.crc-32), including the bit ordering and pre and post processing.